# How to merge google cloud sql and google app engine projects?

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-sql

Our app engine project uses google cloud sql database. Historically cloud SQL was a separate project, and app engine application had permissions to work with it.

Now Google uses a new google cloud console. We see 2 different projects with different project ids.
How can we merge the cloud SQL and app engine projects?
The DB size is about 25Gb and it is used every second so we can't move it to app engine project.
And we can't add app engine project source to Cloud SQL project, there is no App Engine link in new console.

Thanks

Comment: Can you please write to cloud-sql@google.com and indicate the name of the instance and to what project you want it moved? We currently don't provide a way for the users to do that.

Comment: One more observation: you can configure a Cloud SQL instance to follow an App Engine app from a different project.